# Can we link a clang-cl (--target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc) compiled .obj against a clang++ (g++) --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu compiled library?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, linker, clang

Given I compile file `libfmt.dll.a` with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` using `clang++ --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` as below.

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ninja/ninja.exe" 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=23 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld 
--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu 
--driver-mode=g++ -O3 -std=gnu++2b -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ 
-fconstexpr-backtrace-limit=0 -lwinpthread 
-DNDEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS -Wno-unused-command-line-argument" -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld.exe" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS="-lwinpthread" 
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=YES 
-DFMT_INSTALL=NO -DFMT_DOC=NO -DFMT_TEST=NO 
"C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/fmt-master"
```

Then I try to compile a `main()` using `fmt` with `clang-cl` against that `libfmt.dll.a`. The msvc linker fails as

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl fmt::v9::vprint(class fmt::v9::basic_string_view<char>, class fmt::v9::basic_format_args<class fmt::v9::basic_format_context<class fmt::v9::appender, char>>)
>>> referenced by C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ExaAtto-84cclf.obj:(main)
clang++: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However if I link against `fmt.lib` that compiled with clang-msvc as below, it's ok.

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ninja/ninja.exe" 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=23 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld -fms-compatibility-version=19.33.31629 --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.33.31629 --driver-mode=cl /EHsc /std:c++latest /fp:fast /O2 /Ob2 /Gw /MT /Zc:__cplusplus -DNDEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS 
-Wno-unused-command-line-argument" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" 
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=YES -DFMT_INSTALL=NO -DFMT_DOC=NO -DFMT_TEST=NO 
"C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/fmt-master"
```

So I wonder whether we can mix a `clang-gnu` compiled library in msvc linker?

If we can, what do I do wrong here to make msvc linker can't find the symbol?

Comment: Most probably you can't, at least for C++. Could be possible for C, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No absolutely not.

Comment: One thing to consider - if we had been able to mix and match freely, why would there be different `target` parameters?

Comment: @BoP Yes, indeed. Here is another example, `noop_coroutine_handle.promise()` is completely [different](https://github.com/luncliff/coroutine/blob/7edc9624d74436457a66f652aea87719e01a8746/src/coroutine/frame.h#L236) between `clang` and `msvc`. There is (and, of course, will ever be) no such thing as ***ABI stability*** in c++ realm. The c++ standard commitee only tells how the source code text behave. The c++ compiler vendors have their ***very*** own rights completely to tell how the machine behave.