# How to link against MSVC-ABI libraries in Clang/LLVM with GNU toolchain?

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, clang, mingw, llvm

C++ supports function overloading but different compilers use different **name mangling rules**. Nowadays, I have read the source code of LLVM and I know LLVM has implemented MSVC-style name mangling for C++ functions. But I cannot link against MSVC libraries if I use Clang in MSYS2/Clang64 (MinGW-w64) toolchain yet.

Are there any **command line arguments (flags)** to implement this feature in GNU/MinGW toolchains? If not, is it possible to **build a Clang binary** from source to take the same effect?

Similar question: [Can we link a clang-cl (--target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc) compiled .obj against a clang++ (g++) --target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu compiled library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73560088/can-we-link-a-clang-cl-target-x86-64-pc-windows-msvc-compiled-obj-against-a)